# 12.9 LAB: Word frequencies (lists) from a text file

Tags: python

Ex: If the input is:

input1.csv
and the contents of input1.csv are:

hello,cat,man,hey,dog,boy,Hello,man,cat,woman,dog,Cat,hey,boy

the output is:

hello 1
cat 2
man 2
hey 2
dog 2
boy 2
Hello 1
woman 1
Cat 1

My code is:

```
import csv 
user= open(input())
word= user.readline()
lst=word.split(',')
lst2=[]
for i in lst:
       if i not in lst2:
             print(i, lst.count())
      lst2.append(i)
```

but it prints out:
hello 1
cat 2
man 2
hey 2
dog 2
boy 1
Hello 1
woman 1
Cat 1
boy
1

I don't know how to get rid of that extra boy 1.

Comment: "I don't know how to get rid of that extra boy 1." Well, in your own words, why do you think it is there in the first place? Can you think of a rule that tells you, when you're about to print it, whether it's "extra" or not?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option would probably be to use a `collections.Counter` in this case:

```py
from collections import Counter

string = """hello,cat,man,hey,dog,boy,Hello,man,cat,woman,dog,Cat,hey,boy"""

freq_count = Counter(string.split(','))

for word, freq in freq_count.items():
    print(word, freq, end=' ')
```

Output:

```
hello 1 cat 2 man 2 hey 2 dog 2 boy 2 Hello 1 woman 1 Cat 1
```